# Use has_many with polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models, ticket, task, and comments

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :tasks
end
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ticket
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I need to connect Ticket and Comments with `has_many`, I tried

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :comments, through: :tasks, :as => 'commentable'
end
```

But this is not working? How can i properly connect Ticket and Comment so that I can use `ticket.comments` to get all comments attached to that ticket

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by 'not working'. I re-created your code in Rails 6 and it works (by which I mean I can create a ``Ticket`` and then successfully use ``ticket.tasks.comments`` to get at comments through tasks.

Comment: @rmlockerd sure..I need ticket.comments, ticket.task.comments working but my project requirement is ticket.comments

Comment: Sorry, I typed without thinking. I did actually mean that I can use ``ticket.comments`` directly. That is, your code seems to be working for me. Maybe add the ``schema.rb`` contents for the ``Comment`` model to your question to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :comments, through: :tasks
end
```

The `as:` option should not be used here as you're going through the association `comments` on `Task` which defines it.